# Equality of conditional expectations for random vectors

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Let $\left(\Omega,2^\Omega,P\right)$ be a finite probability space. Let $P(\omega)>0 $ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.
Let $X$ be a random
 vector, i.e. a measurable map $\Omega\to\mathbb R^n.$
Show that if $\mathcal B \subset \mathcal A$ is a σ-algebra containing $\sigma(X)$ and if $X'$
is another $\mathcal A$-measurable
random vector of dimension $n'\in\mathbb N$, then, for any Borel function$ f : \mathbb R^{n+n'}
\to\mathbb R$, we have $$E[(f(X,X')\mid \mathcal B](\omega)=E[f(X(\omega),X')\mid \mathcal B](\omega)$$ for any $\omega\in\Omega$.

I do not see how to handle this problem. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Conditional expectations are only defined up to sets of measure $0$. So you cannot prove this equality for every $\omega$ unless you assume that every singleton has positive measure.

Comment: @KaboMurphy It is a good point. Nevertheless, this equality makes sense as an equality of classes of functions on $\Omega$. Namely every member of the left hand side class is a member of the right hand side class and conversely.

Comment: yes ofc I edited the question to fix this problem.

Comment: @RogerSweet your result holds regardless of the existence of nonempty set of measure zero, but in the general case it should be reintrepreted as the equality of families of functions satisfying certain properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that **every $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable on a finite probability space** is integrable.

Denote the class of Borel functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n+n'}$ that satisfy the equality by $\mathcal{F}$.

Pick a Borel subset $A_1\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and a Borel subset $A_2\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n'})$. Then

$$\mathbb{E}\big[\chi_{A_1}(X)\cdot \chi_{A_2}(X')\,\big|\,\mathcal{B}\big] = \chi_{A_1}(X)\cdot\mathbb{E}\big[\chi_{A_2}(X')\,\big|\,\mathcal{B}\big]$$

because $\chi_{A_1}(X)$ is an integrable random variable measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ (c.f. [this property is called "pulling known factors" in this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2)). Hence

$$\mathbb{E}\big[\chi_{A_1}(X)\cdot \chi_{A_2}(X')\,\big|\,\mathcal{B}\big](\omega) = \chi_{A_1}(X)(\omega)\cdot\mathbb{E}\big[\chi_{A_2}(X')\,\big|\,\mathcal{B}\big](\omega) = $$
$$=\bigg(\chi_{A_1}(X)(\omega)\cdot \mathbb{E}\big[\chi_{A_2}(X')\,\big|\,\mathcal{B}\big]\bigg)(\omega) = \bigg(\mathbb{E}\big[\chi_{A_1}(X)(\omega)\cdot \chi_{A_2}(X')\,\big|\,\mathcal{B}\big]\bigg)(\omega)$$

Thus $f(x,x') = \chi_{A_1}(x)\cdot \chi_{A_2}(x')$ in in $\mathcal{F}$. By [the  usual properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2) of conditional expectation the equality holds for all Borel functions. Indeed, $\mathcal{F}$ contains all nonnegative linear combinations of functions of the form 
$$(x,x')\mapsto \chi_{A_1}(x)\cdot \chi_{A_2}(x')$$
By monotone convergence for conditional expectations we deduce that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under monotone convergence of its nonnegative memebers. Finally the equality holds for differences of functions in $\mathcal{F}$. Now the fact that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n+n'})= \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n'})$ and the properties described above imply that $\mathcal{F}$ contains all Borel measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n+n'}$.